# How to merge two ResponseEntity objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4.2. I've to make two separate http calls that return `ResponseEntity<String>`. However, I have to merge them before returning to the caller methods.

Their data structure is exactly similar. Just the content is different. How can I merge this two entities before returning back to the caller ?

Comment: You can't make ONE response for TWO http call.

Answer (score -1):

Use rest template to get your entities inside the entity you want to merge.

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees.xml";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

    final String uri2 = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees2.xml";
    RestTemplate restTemplate2 = new RestTemplate();
    String result2 = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

return result1+result2; //or just your mergeMethod(result1,result2)
```

You can also create a new endpoint with service that is merging the entities with Collections framework or Java 8 stream map.

You can also create a better repository data access object that is joining the tables on DB level - sql, hql, jpql.

Comment: Your code just calls one uri. I have already done that. I need to merge two results in to one. That's the main issue.

Comment: call the second, does it return string too?

Comment: I did. And Yes it does return string. Are you trying to combine/merge the strings ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for

Comment: I tried that and it just merges the strings not the object.  I thought there would be a way to merge the ResponseEntity itself than the String.

Comment: responce entity is just a wraper for an object

Comment: you have to parse or json or xml objects and then merge them